# How to have DBUnit @DatabaseSetup to happen before spring autowiring?

Tags: spring, dbunit, spring-test, spring-test-dbunit

Consider the typical DBUnit Spring Test (see https://github.com/springtestdbunit/spring-test-dbunit) :

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {
"classpath:/META-INF/spring/applicationContext-database.xml",
"classpath:spring-*.xml"
})
@TestExecutionListeners({ DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class,
    DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener.class,
    TransactionalTestExecutionListener.class,
    DbUnitTestExecutionListener.class })
@DatabaseSetup("/dbunit/data.xml")
public class UnitTest {

    @Autowired
    private UnitUnderTest uut;

    @Test
    public void shouldInitDB() {
         ...
    }
}
```

What I have verified is that, and has expected, Autowiring will happen before DatabaseSetup.
This must happen because DBUnit depends on the application context to provide the configured data source.

The problem is that the UnitUnderTest bean has a @PostConstruct where it loads some data from the DB but, since the Autowiring happens before the DBunit setup, the data will not be available at this stage.

Any ideas on how to solve this issue in a clean way?

Comment: Same issue here. Any solutions?

Comment: It's really not a good solution but allowed me to move forward.Create a TestClass that inherits from the object to be autowired and expose a method for external initialization. Use in the @Before test.

Comment: No solution so far. Not even a decent workaround. Will keep searching.

Answer (score 1):

You can you Spring's ResourceDatabasePopulator.

I think you can use something like this

```
@PostConstruct
public void myInMemryPopulator() {
final ResourceDatabasePopulator databasePopulator = new ResourceDatabasePopulator();

        try {

            Resource[] array = resourceResolver.getResources("classpath:/*.sql");       

            for (Resource resource : array) {

                databasePopulator.addScript(resource);
            }
            databasePopulator.populate(dataSource.getConnection());

        } catch (IOException | SQLException e) {
            LOGGER.error("Error in databasePopulator  {} ", e);
        }

    }
```

Comment: if still this not help. You can create Parent Test Case and add Static block in parent test case can call this method

Answer (score 0):

You can have a setup method in your test class and call the post construct method manually. That will work.

Comment: I'm afraid that is a non-solution! In such case I would have to pass the responsibility of calling that method to some other bean. I don't think that there's the need to do that. I'm hopping that spring-test-dbunit will have a cleaner, less intrusive way of testing this kind of scenario, which I'm sure will not be that rare.

Comment: My postconstruct method tries to retrieve database object and it breaks while autowiring, so this solution won't help.

Answer (score 0):

Lazy initialization helped me, I added @Lazy over the @Component* and over the @Autowired in injection points

```
@Lazy
@Component
public class UnitUnderTestImpl {
...
}

@Lazy
@Autowired
private UnitUnderTest uut;
```